# Multiple column groupby with pandas to find maximum value for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below:

| Feature | value | frequency | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| age_45_and_above | No | 2700 | negative |
| age_45_and_above | No | 1707 | positive |
| age_45_and_above | No | 83 | other |
| age_45_and_above | Yes | 222 | negative |
| age_45_and_above | Yes | 15 | positive |
| age_45_and_above | Yes | 8 | other |
| age_45_and_above | [Null] | 323 | negative |
| age_45_and_above | [Null] | 8 | other |
| age_45_and_above | [Null] | 5 | positive |
| talk | No | 20 | negative |
| talk | No | 170 | positive |
| talk | No | 500 | other |
| talk | Yes | 210 | negative |
| talk | Yes | 1500 | positive |
| talk | Yes | 809 | other |
| talk | [Null] | 234 | negative |
| talk | [Null] | 43 | other |
| talk | [Null] | 85 | positive |

and so on.

*for each feature group*, I want to *find the maximum frequency* with all its related row data, like if the feature is  ***age_45_and_above*** then by looking for ***NO*** group we have ***3 rows*** with **different frequency and label**, I want to report the *maximum one with it's related data*.

I've tried `groupby` in different ways:

```
result.groupby(['Feature', 'Value'])['Frequency', 'Predict'].max()
```

or this one, with this one, I'm getting `multi-Index dataframe` which is not the desired results:

```
result.groupby(['Feature', 'Value', 'Predict'])['Frequency'].max()
```

and so many failed attempts with `idxmax`, `transfrom` and ... .

the intended output I'm looking for looks like this:

| Feature | value | frequency | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| age_45_and_above | No | 2700 | negative |
| age_45_and_above | Yes | 222 | negative |
| age_45_and_above | [Null] | 323 | negative |
| talk | No | 500 | other |
| talk | Yes | 1500 | positive |
| talk | [Null] | 234 | negative |

Also, I wonder *how to sum the frequencies for each <<**Feature-value**>> group except the max row* as I don't know *how to locate the max row*, like in here for the first *feature* and *value*, <<**age_45_and_above**-**No**>> *max is 2700*, so the *sum would be 1707+83*.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can [`df.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to return a MultiIndex to columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it by using `merge` on the grouped data.

Based on this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature':['age']*9+['talk']*9,
                   'value':(['No']*3+['Yes']*3+['[Null]']*3)*2,
                   'frequency':[2700,1707,83,222,15,8,323,8,5,20,170,500,210,1500,809,234,43,85],
                   'label':['N','P','O']*6})
```

Using:

```
df.groupby(['Feature','value'],as_index=False)['frequency'].max().merge(df,on=['Feature','Value','frequency'])
```

Outputs:

```
  Feature   value  frequency label
0     age      No       2700     N
1     age     Yes        222     N
2     age  [Null]        323     N
3    talk      No        500     O
4    talk     Yes       1500     P
5    talk  [Null]        234     N
```

Adding the extra column can be done via a simple assignment:

```
df_1['sum_no_max'] = df.groupby(['Feature','value'])['frequency'].sum().values - df_1['frequency'].values
```

Finally outputting:

```
  Feature   value  frequency label  sum_no_max
0     age      No       2700     N        1790
1     age     Yes        222     N          23
2     age  [Null]        323     N          13
3    talk      No        500     O         190
4    talk     Yes       1500     P        1019
5    talk  [Null]        234     N         128
```

Answer (score 4):

using `idxmax` after the `groupby` in a`loc`.

```
print(df.loc[df.groupby(['Feature','value'])['frequency'].idxmax()])
             Feature   value  frequency     label
0   age_45_and_above      No       2700  negative
3   age_45_and_above     Yes        222  negative
6   age_45_and_above  [Null]        323  negative
11              talk      No        500     other
13              talk     Yes       1500  positive
15              talk  [Null]        234  negative
```

and for the `sum` without the `max`, then do the total sum per group and remove the frequency of the row, then select the max row

```
gr = df.groupby(['Feature','value'])['frequency']

res = (
    df.assign(total=gr.transform(sum)-df['frequency'])
      .loc[gr.idxmax()]
)
print(res)
             Feature   value  frequency     label  total
0   age_45_and_above      No       2700  negative   1790
3   age_45_and_above     Yes        222  negative     23
6   age_45_and_above  [Null]        323  negative     13
11              talk      No        500     other    190
13              talk     Yes       1500  positive   1019
15              talk  [Null]        234  negative    128
```

Comment: A lot more in favor of the total - sum